# How to extract unique data on basis of combinations of fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My Schema is

```
var FlatSchema = new Schema({
    tower: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Tower" },
    project: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Project" },
    status: String,
    floor: Number,
    size: String,
    type: String,
    flat_number: String,
    price: Number,
    price_per_unit: Number,
    carpetArea: Number,
    directionFacing: String,
    livingRoomArea: Number,
    kitchenArea: Number,
    balconies: Number,
    bathRooms: Number,
    furnishingState: String,
    flooringType: String,
    FloorPlans_2d: String,
    FloorPlans_3d: String,
    createdAt: { type: Date, 'default': Date.now },
    isDeleted: { type: Boolean, 'default': false }
});
```

I wants to fetch all flats where project id is equals to a given id and results are unique on basis of carpetArea and type.

```
Flat.find({ project: req.params.project, isDeleted: false}, function(err, flats) {
        if (err) { return res.status(500).send(err); }
        if (!flats) { return res.json(401); }
        res.status(200).json(flats);
    });
```

can you please edit my query to get required result ?

Comment: What have you tried? The only query attempt is a very simple one that is nothing like your requirements. Please show a real attempt. Not a code writing service.

Comment: I have no idea about it, that's why I pasted this ques

Comment: It's a very simple thing to look for. The imddediate key words that come to mind about what you are asking return relevant results in every search I can think of. You cannot just post here and ask people to write code for you. Unfortunately your question is also very vague in describing what you expect as output. Too vaugue in fact to warrant the received upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the unique on basic of `carpetArea` and `type` is through [`aggregation`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/), sample codes are

```
Flat.aggregate([
      {$match: { project: req.params.project, isDeleted: false}},
      {$group: {_id: {carpetArea: '$carpetArea', type: '$type'},
                status: {$first: '$status'},
                // other field are here same type above
               }}
      ]);
```